# Mongoose update ref objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Sorry for my bad English.
I use node.js + express.js + mongoose.js
i have this schema in mongoose for groups:

```
var groupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    users: [{type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
    posts: [{type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Post'}]
});
```

and this schema to users:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  login:    { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
  password: String,
  unread:   [{type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Post'}]      
});
```

Group has list of users, related to this group, and list of post, related to this group.
What i want to realize:
`Group1` has users `Mike`, `John` and `Jane`;
When user `Mike` create a new post: 
1)I find current group and select users,related to this group (`Group1` and users `Mike`, `John` and `Jane`);
 2)To users `John` and `Jane` i must set the created post in `unread` field.
(make this to know, which post user has not yet read).
Is it correct? If yes, how can i update this unread field in ref documents? 

I'm tried to do this:
At example: url of the group: `http://localhost:3000/group/first`

```
  app.get('/group/:name', groups.getGroupPage);

  app.post('/group/:name', posts.postCreate);
```

Posts.js

```
var Group = require('../models/group');
var User = require('../models/user');
var Post = require('../models/post');

        exports.postCreate = function(req, res) {
         var post = new Post({
            title: req.body.p_title,
            content: req.body.p_content,
            author: req.user
         });
         Group
                  .update({ name: req.params.name }, {upsert:true}, { "$push": { "users.$.unread": post._id } })
                  .populate('users')
                  .exec(function(err,group) {
                       if (err) res.json(err)
                       console.log(group);
                    }
                  );
        }
```

Thank's for any help.

Comment: Please post code you have tried yourself. We need a bit more information to help you properly. Are you using express? If yes, what is the route you are using? What info are you sending to the express with the request? Do you send the username or user id with the request?

Comment: Added more code, thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your coding style differs a bit from mine but the way I would go about this is following:

```
exports.postCreate = function(req, res) {
  //Create a new post
  var newPost = new Post({
    title: req.body.p_title,
    content: req.body.p_content,
    author: req.user
  });

  //Save the new post
  newPost.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.json(err);
    }
  });

  //Find the group with the name and populate the users field
  Group.findOne({ name: req.params.name })
    .populate('users')
    .exec(function(err, group) {
      if (err) {
        res.json(err);
        console.log(group);
      }
      if (group) {
        //If group is found loop through the users
        for (var i = o; i < group.users.length; i++) {
          //Check if the current user is somebody else as the author
          if (group.users[i]._id != req.user._id) {
            //Push and save the new post to every user in the group
            //We push the _id of the post because we are using references
            group.users[i].unread.push(newPost._id);
            group.users[i].save(function(err) {
              if (err) {
                throw err;
              }
            });
          }
        }
      } else {
        //Do what you need to do if group hasn't been found
      }
    });
};
```

This code assumes that your `req.user` field is the populated as the User schema.

This code is untested. So please debug it. :)

Comment: Thank you very much, @Snekw. I'll check it later)) What do you think, is there a better way to check if a user viewed a post? I think my way is not the best one.

Comment: Well I can think of two different ways. Storing the info about who has viewed to post on the user and other is storing the info on the post. Both have their advantages. If you don't care about knowing easily every user that has viewed the post then storing it on the user is better. If you want to know all users who have viewed to post easily then I would store the info on the post and retrieve from there. You can combine them and store the info on the both and work from there.